# How to set the value of __file__ in an exec() body of code?

Tags: python, exception

I'm using this python3 construct to exec a PY file that I read in.
When the read file throws an exception, the reported location is wrong.
Example:

```
   # create Globals Dict
   fn='foobar.py'
   g={ '__file__' : fn }
   l={ '__file__' : fn }
   text = open(fn).read()
   # goal, pass globals and locals to the exec here.
   exec( text, g, l )
```

where 'foobar.py' contains:

```
print("FILE: %s" % __file__ )
raise Exception('Bang!')
```

The output for `print("File: %s" % __file__ )` is correct

For the exception, it is wrong, I get this:

```
   File "<string>", line 2 in <module>
Exception: Bang!
```

That is not what I am expecting, I purposely want to set the FILENAME where the exception occurred to the name of the file that I read in, in this case: 'foobar.py'